# laptop with ubuntu 14.04 overheating

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, overheating, nvidia-prime

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 on Lenovo Y580, I' have 2 graphic cards, nvidia and intel, I have noticed it's overheating a lot. Following some tutorial I removed `bumbelbee` and tried to install `nvidia-prime` (it said I already had newest version) but when I run `nvidia x server settings` I don't see `nvidia-prime` options like its supposed to be.
Am I going the right way to solve overheating problem? what to do next? (the tutorial I was using ends at setting options for `nvidia-prime` in `nvidia x server settings` which I can't see) or is there another way to stop overheating?

Edit: ok I figured out it's because two graphic cards are running at the same time, I don't need nvidia card to be running on ubuntu since I use it only on windows, how can I disable nvidia card?